# Subshell exit code affects logging

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this bash script:

```
echo "x" & X=$!
echo "y" & Y=$!
( echo "z" ; exit 0; ) & Z=$!  # this line

wait ${X} && echo "X $?" 
wait ${Y} && echo "Y $?" 
wait ${Z} && echo "Z $?"
```

when I change exit 0 to exit 1, the last echo statement of the script does not execute. For example, here is the output when the exit code is 0:

```
x
X 0
z
y
Y 0
Z 0
```

but when I change it to 1:

```
x
y
X 0
z
Y 0
```

I am assuming what's in the parentheses should be executed in a subshell. Anyone know why my code does this?

Answer (score 4):

As documented in `help wait`:

> Returns the status of ID

So, if the process exited with `1`, wait returns `1` and the `&&` short circuits by not executing the second command. Try `;` instead of `&&` if you want to print the value regardless of success of the first command.